# DomDocument получить между div контент с тегами

Tags: php, dom

Как получить между дивом весь контент с тегами.

Пример контент `<div class="wrap"><a href=".."></a><span></span></div>`

Нужно получить `<a href=".."></a><span></span>` то есть любой контент между Div

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://xx.com/');
// создаем новый dom-объект
$dom = new domDocument("1.0", "utf-8");

// загружаем html в объект
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$counter = 0;
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('header') as $row)
{
    if ($counter++ == 0) continue;
    echo $row->nodeValue.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Уточните инструмент, с помощью которого необходимо получить результат.

Comment: $dom = new domDocument

Comment: if ($counter++ == 0) continue; Никогда не будет выполняться.

Comment: Я х3 она скрыла первый вывод head значетет выполняется)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно вот так:

```
<?php
$html = '<div class="wrap"><a href=".."></a><span></span></div>';

preg_match('/<div class="wrap">(.*)<\/div>/s', $html, $content);

echo $content[1];

?>
```

Comment: Этт способ сложный и работает далеко не всегда. `<div class="wrap"><div class="another"></div><a href="..."></a> Этот текст не будет выбран</div>`

Comment: @ilyaplot я решил задачу по условию из примера. для вашего случая нужно использовать так `preg_match('/<div class="wrap">(.*)<\/div>/s', $html, $content);`

Comment: Мне встречалось немало примеров, в которых какой-нибудь phpQuery экономил недели трудозатрат разработчиков, а регулярки просто не смогли. Для второго примера я могу составить исходник, который тоже не сработает так, как ожидает автор.

Comment: мы сейчас боремся с противником в слепую. вы хотите посмотреть на что я способен или почему вы мне выдвигаете какие-то задачи? то, что просил автор я выполнил, а то, что хотите Вы, будьте добры, давайте решать в новом вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$html = '<div class="wrap"><a href=".."></a><span></span></div>';

function DOMinnerHTML(DOMNode $element) 
{
    $innerHTML = ""; 
    $children  = $element->childNodes;

    foreach ($children as $child) 
    { 
        $innerHTML .= $element->ownerDocument->saveHTML($child);
    }

    return $innerHTML; 
}

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$divs =  $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');

foreach ($divs as $div) {
    echo DOMinnerHTML($div).PHP_EOL; // <a href=".."></a><span></span>
}
```

Comment: Такая проблема как мой код `foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('header') as $row)
{
    if ($counter++ == 0) continue;
    echo $row->nodeValue.'<br>';
}` совместить с вашим примером?

Comment: Вместо 'div' сделать 'header', вместо .PHP_EOL .'<br>'

Comment: А также код который сверху почему то всё повторяет по 2 раза тоесть 1 див выводит 2 раза

Comment: Мне нужно выводить Header снизу их контенты (дивы).

Comment: Вообще ничего не понимаю из того, что Вы написали.

Comment: Я хочу получить getElementsByTagName('header') а также getElementsByTagName('div'). что тут не понятного?.То есть так как я знаю 2 елемента на foreach нельзя вращать...

Comment: Перебирайте сначала header, а потом div. Можно положить ссылки на элементы в массив и работать с ним по индексам или еще как-то. Очень много абстракции в вопросе и не понятно, каков должен быть результат.